# Using IPFS hashes in stellar transaction / MEMO

Tags: transactions

I wonder if it is possible to send a IPFS Hash in a transaction MEMO. No accepted MOMO-Type allows me to enter a Multihash.

Or did i get something wrong with 32-byte hashes which is not the IPFS-Hash format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's currently not possible to send multihash as a transaction memo but adding multihash memo support is being [discussed](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/issues/32).

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found a way. It includes some background programming but its not to complicated to get the valid Qm. hash after sending ther transaction. 
http://abcxyz.de/2018/02/08/using-ipfs-as-memo-in-stellar-transaction/

cheers

Comment: It won't always work because multihash can be longer than 32 bytes.

Comment: mhh thats why i'm using the pure sha256 hash generated by go-ipfs without the prefix before base58 is applied.